# Using Iterator with ModelBuilder for clipping and splitting in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, splitting, iterator

My input feature class is a county-wide dataset and the input clip feature is a township’s ‘section.’  I have 576 different ‘sections’ in which to clip the county-wide data out to.  Though I dont have 576 different section feature classes to clip by, I was just using a definition query to select which particular section to clip out to.  I would like to use ModelBuilder to streamline clipping 576 sections of countywide dataset.

How would I set up ModelBuilder to incorporate an iterator into the model for this particular case?

[image]

The above model successfully split a township's contours into 36 sections. I need to run it 15 more times to achieve my end goal. I need to add an iterator to batch split out the remaining 15 townships. I put an orange background on the items that need to have the expression or output filename changed when a different township is being run through the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an Advanced level license of ArcGIS Desktop then there may be no need for you to use ModelBuilder.  Instead you could use the [Split](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm) tool which:

> Splits an input with overlaying features to create a subset of output
>   feature classes.
>
> The Split Field parameter's unique values form the names of the output
>   feature classes. These are saved in the target workspace.